# How can do i add conditions in condition

Tags: php

I have this code

```
<?php if (is_page_template()) {
} else {
get_sidebar();
}
?>
```

I want to integrate two options  to the if condition

```
if (is_front_page())
```

how do i put it together in the php code so it would work

i tried

```
<?php if (is_page_template()) ||  (is_front_page()){
} else {
get_sidebar();
}
?>
```

but it does not work. sorry I'm not really good at programming.

any help would be appreciate it :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just had two extra parenthesis.

### The Good

```
<?php 
if (is_page_template() ||  is_front_page())
{
} else {
    get_sidebar();
}
?>
```

### The Mistake

```
<?php if (is_page_template()) ||  (is_front_page()){
                            ^-----^  Not Required
```

Comment: Just to precise: "||" means at least one of the two conditions must be true. If you want both conditions to be true, use "&&".

Comment: I knew it was the parentheses. I tried something like that too but I messed it up too. haha Thanks a lot it did work :)

Answer (score 0):

There is issue with the closing bracket ')' of if condition. Try this.

```
<?php if (is_page_template() ||  is_front_page()){
} else {
get_sidebar();
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You close the conditional too early

```
<?php if (is_page_template()) ||  (is_front_page()){
```

**this will work:**

```
<?php if (is_page_template() ||  is_front_page()){
```